# Connection cost using file_get_contents on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

With PHP file_get_contents can make URL connection, and it uses allow_url_fopen to be ON in php.ini

I'm aware AWS servers allow that kind of configuration, but my question is if ther is any cost billing for the internet trafic.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Data_Transfer

Comment: Thanks! I was searching with just tecnical keywords...